# Only changing last digit in list of integers

Tags: python, for-loop

The program must take a value such as 3, and return a list as followed:

```
[10.1 , 11.1 , 12.1 , 13.1 , 10.2 , 11.2 , 12.2 , 13.2 , 10.3 , 11.3 , 12.3 , 13.3]
```

See how the value 3 will return 3 sets of integers in the range of 10 to 13, with the final decimal increasing by 1 each set.

Here is my current loop (not working) that returns the list `[10.1,11.1,12.1,13.1,14.1,15.1,16.1]` if the "value" is 7 for example

```
emptyList=[] 
adder=10
for g in range(0,value):
    if value > 3 and value < 13:
        emptyList.append(adder+0.1)
        adder+=1 
 return emptyList
```

Comment: To start with, you’re never changing the value after the decimal point...

Comment: The first problem is: due to floating point imprecision, there is not really such thing as a "last digit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single list comprehension as follows. Here, `j` loops over 10 to the last number you want and `i` ranges from 1 to 3. `i/10` gives you the fractional part.

```
lst = [j+i/10 for j in range(10,14) for i in range(1,4)]
print (lst)

# [10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 11.1, 11.2, 11.3, 12.1, 12.2, 12.3, 13.1, 13.2, 13.3]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l = []
adder = 10
value = 3
for i in range (1, value + 1):
    for j in range(0, value + 1):
        l.append(adder + i/10 + j)
```